# Android: keep timer running when app closed

Tags: java, android, timer

My app needs to update its data every 24hrs. The user should not be able to access some parts of the app if its out of date.

When the app starts up, I check if the database is out of date.  But, the users might keep the app open of in the background for a long time, and I need to alert them when the update is required.

What's the best way to do this?  My Initial thought was to use some kind of Handler thread and save a timestamp somewhere every time the app was paused, and then calculate the new time and restart the timer on resumer.

This leaves two questions:

- How can I detect whenever my app is paused or resumed, regardless of activity?
- And what is the best idiom for a long-running timer in Android? (keeping in mid that it has to be able to modify UI components ie show an alert when he time is up)

Answer (score 1):

You could do that, but you should not, instead store the time stamp in the shared preferences whenever the app get closed, when open again read that value again and calculate the difference by getting the actual **timestamp**.... then after that update if necessary the lapsed time!

timeStamp is just a long value..

and you can get it by just calling the `System.currentTimeMillis()`

and for the shared preferences use the Class `SharedPreferences`

Answer (score 0):

You can have a Service do the query every 24 hours for you and notify the user if it fails. You can use the AlarmManager for that. Eg:

```
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent m_intent = new Intent(this, YourService.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 2, m_intent, 0);
alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 24 * 60 * 60, pi);
```

The Service can then ask the AlrmManager to call itself after 24 hours again using the above code only.

NOTE: Alarms can be cancelled by the system or the user (force stop). So, this solution comes with its caveats.